# SQL Compact 4 EF model in VS2010 windows app

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

In VS2010 sp1 with SSCE 4.0 tools for vs2010 sp1 installed, Adding a new ADO.net entity data model and generate model does not show SQL compact 4.0 even though i have the tools, sp1 installed, however, it works flawlessly in a web project where sql server compact 4 is listed as an option in the generate data model screen

there are numerous posts on workaround etc. but most are about 8+ months old

wondering if there's any recent updates which makes it just work - i.e. create a ssce 4.0 ef model in vs2010 sp1 windows projects rather than go through the workarounds every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no updates from Microsoft (other than VS 11), but my SQL Server Compact Toolbox add-in allows you to create an EDMX (ADO.NET Entity Data Model) in any desktop project type: http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com